# Range of a equation

Tags: functions

Consider a question :
Find the range of 
$f(x)= \frac{x^2 - 4}{x - 2} $

I found two methods for solving this

**Method 1:**
The domain of this function is $\mathbb{R} - {2}$ .So if $x$ is not equal to $2$ , $f(2)$ does  not lie in the range $f(2)=2+2=4$

THEREFORE **range=$\mathbb{R}-{4}$**

**Method 2** 
Let $\frac{x^2- 4}{x-2} = y
\iff x^2-4=xy-2y \iff x^2-(y)x-(4-2y)=0$ as $x$ is real
 ${ b^2 -4ac\ge 0}$
    $ y^2+4(4-2y)\ge 0 \iff (y-4)^2 \ge 0$

THEREFORE range is ${\mathbb{R}}$

Two different ranges

Comment: I think in the second method, in the first step you should have considered what happens at $x=2$... Because you multiplied both sides by $x-2$.

Answer (score 0):

The first method doesn't make sense: since $2$ does not blong to the domain of $f$, $f(2)$ is meaningless.

For the second method, you seem to have forgotten that $2$ does not blong to the domain of $f$. Besides, if $x\neq2$, $\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}=y\iff x+2=y$. But, since $x$ can be any real number other than $2$, $y$ can be any real number other than $4$. So, the range is $\mathbb R\setminus\{4\}$.

Comment: That if we follow second method we have to be careful about 2

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much sir